# Orbiting a 3d camera around an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, 3d

After googling I haven't found the anwser to this question so I am going to try it here.

Using (2d) canvas I made a 3d world in javascript and even a 3d camera that works fine with it. However, the camera is a 'free camera' so when you rotate, the camera rotates around itself.

Now I would like to have the camera rotate around an in-world object but I have a lot of trouble understanding how to do that.

I tried the following formula but it freaks out before I even attempt to rotate...

```
this.x += (Math.sin(this.yd * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance);
this.z -= (Math.cos(this.yd * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance);
```

**UPDATED SO FAR**
Thanks to the anwser provided by WojtekT below, I got to the following code, it turns the camera arounds the object, but also seem to zoom in... this might just be my eyes fooling me since the distance variable barely changes (I think there is a tiny rounding issue, but other then that it gives the expected result)

```
this.y = (Math.sin(this.yd * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance + this.targetY);
this.z = (Math.cos(this.yd * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance + this.targetZ);
```

Where this.yd is the speed it should run in degrees.

What formula do I need?

**EDIT**:
I am unsure what pieces of code can help solve this problem, so here is the complete source:

http://clanpvp.com/sol
http://clanpvp.com/js/sol/camera.js < Camera object, this probably.

For debugging reasons, a new frame is loaded when a keyup event is triggered.
Also for debugging, the target object is a fixed point. at the center of the screen.

The arrow keys move the camera, the wasd keys turn the camera, so far only W and S do something and they do it wrong thanks to above code...

Comment: What do you mean by 'it freaks out'?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is going on, but the camera seems to move backward each frame. My guess is that the formula I use is just plain wrong and so the camera does something completely different then what I want

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what code can help solve this problem, so I'll just link the project instead.

Comment: yes pls, that would definitely help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this formula to work you must have some variable that changes each frame. For example variable `time`:

```
time += this.yd;
this.x = (Math.sin(time * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance);
this.z = (Math.cos(time * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance);
```

Otherwise `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` return same value each frame.
Basically for something to rotate you need to provide angle that changes with time. In this example angle is variable `time`.

EDIT:
I've replaced `+=` with `=` in my answer. This calculation gives you correct exact `x` and `z` values so you don't need to do any incrementations.

EDIT 2:

This formula is also missing center of rotation. Proper calculation should look like this:

```
this.x = (Math.sin(this.yd * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance + object_looked_at.x);
this.z = (Math.cos(this.yd * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance + object_looked_at.z);
```

Comment: this.yd is altered when the user presses a key, sorry for not being clear about that. I've listed the source so hopefull that makes things more clear

Comment: Is `this.yd` speed of rotation or rotation itself?

Comment: this.yd is the rotation itself

Comment: It seems that you don't need to increment your `.x` and `.z`. I've edited my answer and replaced `+=` and `-=` with `=`.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect your anwser, (minus the time variable) but the camara still doesn't behave (even without any input)

Comment: Yes, now i noticed that you also need to provide center of rotation. It could be position of object that you look at. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That almost did the trick, one extra addition was replacing the x with the y positions. It now acts a bit weird when going to far though...

Comment: It seems that aside from turning the camera it also moves the camera closer,